# Python can't open text file: "FileNotFoundError"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with opening a text file in Python 3:
I want to open a text file that I created earlier and its name is "pythontest". the file contains some numbers and words. In order to open that in Python I do:

```
with open ('pythontest.txt') as test:
    file = test.read()
    print(file)
```

But Python is giving me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pythontest.txt
```

How can I fix the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, `pythontest` <> `pythontest.txt`, isn't it?

Comment: Where do you run your Python program and what's the location of your textfile?

Comment: `pythontest.txt` does not exist in `import os; print(os.getcwd())`/current working directory or you are executing the script with insufficient permission (your program cannot view the filesystem and thus not the file.)

Comment: @Dominique I run python program in anaconda in spyder

Comment: @Jan I changed it but it gives this error:        file=a.read()
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that the file is in the current work directory:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. How should I do that? just write this code in python?

Comment: Yes in the same file just to get the current work directory. because when you don't write the full path of the file (like in your case), then python interpreter will assume that the file is in the work directory. so you have three options: 1- use the full path of the file, 2- or change the work directory into the folder that contains the file , 3- or copy the file into the work directory that you get from executing this command

Comment: Thank you the directory is:  Current working directory: C:\Users\Soheil_PC\.spyder-py3

Comment: I know I should change the directory but don't know change it to what? I want to change in order to every time I create file in desktop python recognize that

Comment: should be C:\Users\Soheil_PC\Desktop\Python38-32  ?

Comment: Thank you very much I copy file in work directory( method 3) and it worked!

Comment: welcome, just a hint:
import os
dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(dirname)
this will change the work directory to you python file directory

Answer (score 1):

with `os` module check if you're on the right working directory(as same as your text file).

make sure you have your text file in the current working directory

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. How Can I check it?

Comment: I entered this code and it show:  runfile('C:/Users/Soheil_PC/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Soheil_PC/.spyder-py3')

Answer (score 0):

Provide full path  of the file. For example:

```
with open('c:/Users/joshu/Downloads/ShortSelling.csv') as f:
    file = f.read()
    print(file)
```

That will help you to open the file.

Comment: If you are in linux environment just get the full path of the file using  pwd cmd.